# defining copy constructor and assignment operator

Tags: c++, class, corruption

It's my first time dealing with classes in C++. I was wondering if somebody could help me to properly design a copy constructor and an assignment operator for the following class.

The following post talks about the rule of threes,

[What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Although, it was not very clear how to implement it for my code.

INFO.h

```
#ifndef INFO_H
#define INFO_H

class INFO{
public:
        std::string label, type;
        unsigned int num;
        double x, y, z, velx, vely, velz;
        void print(std::ostream& stream);
        void mod_print(std::ostream& stream);
        void read(std::istream& stream);
        void mod_read(std::istream& stream);
        double distance(INFO *i,double L);
        INFO(std::istream& stream);
        INFO(){};
};

#endif
```

INFO.cpp

```
#include "INFO.h"

void INFO::print(std::ostream& stream)
{
        stream << label <<'\t'<< type <<'\t'<< num <<'\t'<< x<<'\t'<<y<<'\t'<< z << '\n';
}
void INFO::mod_print(std::ostream& stream)
{
        stream << label <<'\t'<< type <<'\t'<< x<<'\t'<<y<<'\t'<< z << '\n';
}
void INFO::read(std::istream& stream)
{
        stream >> label >> type >> num >> x >> y >> z;
}
void INFO::mod_read(std::istream& stream)
{
        stream >> label >> type >> x >> y >> z;
}
double INFO::distance(INFO *i,double L)
{
        double delx = i->x - x - std::floor((i->x-x)/L + 0.5)*L;
        double dely = i->y - y - std::floor((i->y-y)/L + 0.5)*L;
        double delz = i->z - z - std::floor((i->z-z)/L + 0.5)*L;
        return delx*delx + dely*dely + delz*delz;
}
INFO::INFO(std::istream& stream)
{
        stream >> label >> type >> num >> x >> y >> z;
}
```

Comment: don't use all caps locks for your id's. It's a convention for macros. Use `class info` or `class Info`. Never `class INFO`

Answer (score 2):

Since your class contains these member variables

```
std::string label, type;
unsigned int num;
double x, y, z, velx, vely, velz;
```

In the copy constructor you copy the values present in the reference object. So, define the constructor as below

```
INFO::INFO(const INFO &Ref)
{
    // copy the attributes
    this->label = Ref.label;
    this->type = Ref.type;
    this->num = Ref.num;
    this->x = Ref.x;
    this->y = Ref.y;
    this->z = Ref.z;
    this->velx = Ref.velx;
    this->vely = Ref.vely;
    this->velz = Ref.velz;
}
```

For the assignment operator you need to write a function like this

```
INFO& INFO::operator= (const INFO &Ref)
{
    // copy the attributes
        this->label = Ref.label;
        this->type = Ref.type;
        this->num = Ref.num;
        this->x = Ref.x;
        this->y = Ref.y;
        this->z = Ref.z;
        this->velx = Ref.velx;
        this->vely = Ref.vely;
        this->velz = Ref.velz;

    // return the existing object
    return *this;
}
```

Hope this works, let me know

Comment: When compiling its giving the following errors: ' error: definition of implicitly-declared ‘info::info(const info&)’ ' and ' error: definition of implicitly-declared ‘info& info::operator=(const info&)’ '.

Comment: Because you need to add the prototype in the INFO.h file also `INFO& INFO::operator= (const INFO &Ref);` and `INFO::INFO(const INFO &Ref);`

Comment: Would a destructor be designed in a similar manner?

Comment: You don't need a destructor unless you use dynamic memory allocation. Please refer to the basics of [OOPS](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/)